# ASP.NET FaceBook App Development -

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, codeplex

I have downloaded both samples for the Facebook Developer Kit from Codeplex and Facebook.NET followed both tutorials down to the word - But as soon as I browse to me app on Facebook I am getting the following error for BOTH versions?

> API Error Code: 100
>
> API Error Description: Invalid parameter
>
> Error Message: Requires valid next URL.

Anyone else had this problem?  I'm struggling to find an answer to what the error actually means?  Especially as the starts kits are supposed to work out the box?

Comment: Try looking at this discussion and see if it helps: http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=110010620072&topic=13175

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable data permissions.

Settings > Migrations > "New Data Permissions" > Disabled